# Re-render template of directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, renderscript

I have two arrays with the same properties (`transaction.blackCard` and `transaction.whiteCard`). The controller set the color to `scope.cardSelected.color` but the directive is already rendered. In the view, I have the same input to black and white cards so the directive is responsible for hearing the events of the fields.

I need to re-render the directive when `scope.cardSelected.color` change into controller to `someVar` refresh its value.

I only copy some fragment of the code.

**Directive:**

```
directive('someComponent', ['$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $timeout, ) {
        var template = '\<div> THIS IS MY TEMPLATE </div>';
        return {
           restrict: 'E',
           template: template,
           scope: {
               cardSelected: '=cardSelected',
               transaction: '=transaction'
           },
           link: function(scope, element) {

           var someVar = 'transaction.blackCard';
           if(scope.cardSelected.color === 'WHITE'){
               someVar = 'transaction.whiteCard';
           }

           scope.$watch(someVar+'.letter', function(newValue) {
               ....
           });

           scope.$watch(someVar+'.shape', function(newValue) {
               ....
           });

           scope.$watch(someVar+'.character', function(newValue) {
               ....
           });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**:

```
controller('someColorCardCtrl', ['$scope',  function ($scope){
    $scope.selectCardColor = function(color){
        $scope.cardSelected.color = color;
    });
});
```

Sorry for my english!